# Cannot click on the pop-up button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML Code. Clicking on the **Buy now for 200** will show the below pop up with **Buy now, ok and close**

```
<button class="btn-standard buyButton currency-coins">Buy Now for 200</button>
```

[image]

```
<div class="dialog-body">
 <button class>
 span class="btn-text">Ok</span>
 <span class="btn-subtext"></span>
 </button>
 <button class>
 <span class="btn-text">Ok</span>
 <span class="btn-subtext"></span>
 </button>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to automatize the process, and I did something like this in javascript but it didn't work for **the last step, click on OK**.

So below is my code.

```
$("button:contains('Buy Now')").on('click', function(){

$("span:contains('Ok')").click();}); //alert("hello") is working, but click on OK button didn't

----------------------------
$("button:contains('Buy Now')").click(); // is doing nothing for Ok button click.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger the click event of the span on the click of the 'Buy Now' button, if I understood correctly.

The code you have should work. All you need to do is create a function to do something about the click event of the span.

```js
$("button:contains('Buy Now')").on('click', function() {

  $("span:contains('Ok')").trigger('click');
  return false;

});


$("span:contains('Ok')").on('click', function() {

  //do something here
  alert("This works");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class>
    Buy Now
  </button>

<div class="dialog-body">
  <button class>
    <span class="btn-text">Ok</span>
    <span class="btn-subtext"></span>
  </button>
  <button class>
    <span class="btn-text">Cancel</span>
    <span class="btn-subtext"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, and I will come back with a feedback

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered.